# Teapot Riddle no.27

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Good luck to you all!

---

### The Rules

- I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
- Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
- You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

---

### The Puzzle

First:

> My first teapot is typically for one person.

Second:

> My second teapot is a person in charge.

Third:

> My third teapot is an umpire.

Fourth:

> My fourth teapot is a metal socket for railroads.

Fifth:

> My fifth teapot is to carry someone during a celebration.

Sixth:

> My sixth and final teapot is used for sitting.

Comment: You're on a teapot roll :P

Comment: Well I was challenged by another user to create a few with increasing difficulty and thus I am. LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second attempt:

> Chair

My first teapot is typically for one person.

> A seat for one person

My second teapot is a person in charge.

> Chair as in Chairman

My third teapot is an umpire.

> Chair umpire

My fourth teapot is a metal socket for railroads.

> The earliest rail chairs, made of cast iron and introduced around 1800, were used to fix and support cast-iron rails at their ends - Wikipedia

My fifth teapot is to carry someone during a celebration.

> Yup, it's chair :P

My sixth and final teapot is used for sitting.

> A chair.

OLD ATTEMPT:

Could it be

> tie

My first teapot is typically for one person.

> A tie to be worn by one person

My second teapot is a person in charge.

> ?

My third teapot is an umpire.

> Tie = draw?

My fourth teapot is a metal socket for railroads.

> I saw there's something called cross-tie or so

My fifth teapot is to carry someone during a celebration.

> ?

My sixth and final teapot is used for sitting.

> Umm... Chair tie?

Comment: The answer is in your answer but is not your answer. LOL +1 From me! Good attempt, keep up the good work and you'll have it!

Comment: Hahaha! I did not realize it at all till you mentioned! XD

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> LEAD?

My first teapot is typically for one person.

> This may reference the fact that there's usually only one "lead" in many situations: one lead actor or actress, one person who leads a competition, one boss for a group, etc.

My second teapot is a person in charge.

> The person who leads a group towards an objective.

My third teapot is an umpire.

> In some sports, there's the "lead official" and there are other assisting officials.

My fourth teapot is a metal socket for railroads.

> Lead is a strong material.

My fifth teapot is to carry someone during a celebration.

> ?

Comment: Good attempt! I definitely enjoyed the answer but this isn't it.

Comment: Lead was also the answer of the (let me guess) first fanmade teapot riddle (no.8/9) don't remember quite but i know it was used

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> Coach

My first teapot is typically for one person.

> Refers to an instructor

My second teapot is a person in charge.

> Refers to what coaches as a person do

My third teapot is an umpire.

> He is also a referee

My fourth teapot is a metal socket for railroads.

> Coaches of a train

My fifth teapot is to carry someone during a celebration

> To coach someone means to carry someone.. not sure about this hint

Comment: Another good answer, but not it either. +1

Answer (score 2):

I believe it may be:

> LAP

My first teapot is typically for one person.

> Not sure on this one

My second teapot is a person in charge.

> You "drop things in someone's lap" to give them responsibility (not sure about this one)

My third teapot is an umpire.

> Thinking there is an umpire with the initial L.A.P.?  But couldn't find a reference.

My fourth teapot is a metal socket for railroads.

> There are lap sockets, though I didn't find a connection to railroads

My fifth teapot is to carry someone during a celebration.

> Victory lap

My sixth and final teapot is used for sitting.

> One person can sit on another's lap

Comment: After reading your response to @nikki, I see what the actual answer is, but I'll let them discover it since it's right there and I don't see how it fits with a couple of the clues yet.

Comment: Oh man, I'm seeing this only now! You should have gone ahead! :)

Comment: +1 from me though :)

Comment: Ha - thanks.  I was still trying to figure out #5, which I just saw is a British reference.  I wouldn't have found it without her comment, so seemed fair to let you discover it :)